# jQuery validation engine in Struts 2 not working

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, struts2, jquery-validation-engine

My Eclipse Dynamic Web Project structure is as follows:

**WebContent:**

- CSS

  - (Various css files used)
- JavaScript

  - (JS files)
- Pages

  - Page1.jsp
  - Page2.jsp
- META-INF
- WEB-INF

  - lib
  - web.xml

I'm using the jQuery validation engine for front end and Ajax validation in `page1.jsp`, the Ajax part calls an action class which then validates the data.

**`page1.jsp`:**

```xml
<script>
    $(document).ready (function ()
    {
        $("#subform").validationEngine('attach', {
            autoHidePrompt : true , 
            autoHideDelay : 5000,
            ajaxFormValidation : true,
            ajaxFormValidationURL : 'ajaxVal/FormVal',
            ajaxFormValidationMethod : 'post',
            onBeforeAjaxFormValidation : function (form, options) {
                console.log ("before ajax validation in function");
                form.validationEngine ('hideAll');
                $('#txtlname').validationEngine ('showPrompt', 'Validating your name please wait', 'load', true);
                return true;
            },
            onAjaxFormComplete : function (status, form, json, option) {
                console.log ("ajax validation done");
                console.log ("status: " + status);
                console.log ("data returned " + json);
                console.log ("checking status now");
                if (status) {
                    console.log ("status good, detaching now");
                    form.validationEngine ('hideAll');
                    form.validationEngine ('detach');
                    form.submit ();
                }
            }
        }); 
    });
</script>


<title>Form Validation test</title>
</head>

<body>

<div>                           
    <form id = "subform" action = "submitForm" method = "post">         <br><br><br>
        First Name: <input id = "txtfname" name = "txtfname" type = "text" class = "validate[required]" 
            placeholder = "enter emp name" />
        Last name: <input id = "txtlname" name = "txtlname" type = "text" placeholder = "enter emp lname" 
                class = "validate[required, ajax[ajaxStrutsCall]]" />
        Age: <input id = "txtage" name = "txtage" type = "text" placeholder = "enter age"  />           
        <input id ="cmdsubmit" type = "submit" name = "cmdsubmit" value = "click here" />
    </form>
</div>
    
</body>
```

the Ajax call in the class attribute of the `"last name"` input tag is in  `jquery.validationEngine-en.js` it is:

```js
"ajaxStrutsCall": {
                "url": "ajaxVal/LnameVal",
                "alertTextOk": "Your last name seems ok",
                "alertText": "Bad Last name",
                "alertTextLoad": "Validating, please wait"
            },
```

**my `struts.xml`:**

```xml
<struts>
<constant name = "struts.devMode" value = "true" />

<package name = "strutsaction" extends = "struts-default">
    <action name = "submitForm" class = "validation.action.JqueryAction" method = "execute">
        <result name = "success">/Pages/page2.jsp</result>
    </action>       
</package>


<package name = "ajaxAction" namespace = "/ajaxVal" extends = "json-default">

    <action name = "LnameVal" class = "validation.struts.AjaxStrutsAction" method = "execute">
        <result name = "success" type = "json" />
    </action>
    
    <action name = "FormVal" class = "ajax.form.validator.FormValidation" method = "execute">
        <result name = "success" type = "json" />
    </action>
    
</package>
```

Now, the thing is that all the code was working perfectly when `page1.jsp` and `page2.jsp` were one folder up, i.e. in the `WebContent`, as soon as I added them to the `Pages/` folder, the Ajax validation calls do not happen, even though the action to the next page does.

I figured that this this is because the URL is not matching, when i tried accessing the struts class in my tomcat server as the following URL worked:

```
http://localhost:8080/AjaxTest/ajaxVal/LnameVal
```

However, this did not:

```
http://localhost:8080/AjaxTest/Pages/ajaxVal/LnameVal
```

I even changed the namespace in my `ajaxAction` package in `struts.xml` to `/Pages/ajaxVal`, but no dice.

Answer (score 1):

You're using a relative URL for the validation action:

```
ajaxFormValidationURL : 'ajaxVal/FormVal'
```

You should either use the `<s:url>` tag or make the paths absolute. That it worked until you moved it provides the biggest clue; relative URLs are inherently fragile when you start moving things around.

IMO hand-coding URLs is a bit brittle, and this is one of the reasons.

Unrelated, but I'd probably set the `"valaction"` package namespace to `"/"`.

Comment: i tried <s:url namespace ='/ajaxVal' action = 'FormVal' /> but it gave me this error in firebug: SyntaxError: invalid regular expression flag a
ajaxFormValidationURL : /AjaxTest/ajaxVal/FormVal.action

Comment: the "valaction" package is improperly named, im sorry about that and ive edited it, its actually the struts action class thats called on submit, and thats actually working fine. Also even if i do use `<s:url>` i wont be able to do so in `jquery.validationEngine-en.js`.

Comment: also, ive never used a namespace with my struts package (after editing, `valaction` is `strutsaction`) is there any particular advantage to it? it seems to work fine without it too

Comment: sorry, my bad, `<s:url namespace ='/ajaxVal' action = 'FormVal' />` is working for the form validation, i forgot to add quotes, dumb mistake. but the other problem, for jquery.validationEngine-en.js still holds

Comment: @doggkilla Of course, because JS files aren't normally processed by JSP. You need to build a bridge between your JSP and your JS, either by providing a mechanism to retrieve a value from the HTML DOM (e.g., hide a value in a hidden DOM object, use a `data-` attribute, etc.) or   access a JS value created in your JSP page, etc.

Comment: but keeping my jsp pages in the WebContent folder will sort out these issues too right? there wont be a case where there will be a problem?

Comment: @doggkilla Do you mean just keep everything at the root level? That would fix one type of problem, but create an organizational one.

Comment: actually i have to give a demo by fri, and i need the ajax part, so for now, ill keep my jsp pages in the `WebContent` folder. would that create any problem that i havent anticipated, apart from there being a clutter of pages in the folder?

Answer (score 0):

To submit to the action, needs to put the action URL. Using Struts tags requires taglib definition

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
```

change the form tag to

```
<form id="subform" action="<s:url action='submitForm'/>" method="POST">
```

the same you should write to get the url for the validation URL

```
ajaxFormValidationURL : '<s:url namespace="/ajaxVal" action="FormVal"/>',
```

remember always use URL tag to render URLs.

Comment: hi, thats just the thing i dont understand, the struts action class (called on form submit) is working perfectly (once i remove the ajax validators of course otherwise the form wont submit), only the ajaxFormValidationURL and the ajax call from jquery.validationEngine-en.js arent working

Comment: thanks, this works perfectly! but the last name text field uses an ajax validation as well from the `ajax[ajaxStrutsCall]` this calls the rule from the jquery.validationEngine-en.js file which holds the url, and i cant use struts tags there :/ (see my question for edit)

Comment: also i dont understand why this happens, i dont need to use the url tag for the `action` attribute mapped in the form but i do for the rest. when i specify the class in struts.xml, shouldnt i be able to call it from anywhere i want to?

Comment: because js is not compilable code, the last question is not clear, what do you mean "from anywhere"?

Comment: my last two questions are unrelated, 1) how do i set the url in `jquery.validationEngine-en.js`? 2) the struts action `submitForm` in `strutsaction` package can be called by the form in page1, whether page1 is in the `pages/` folder or the `WebContent` folder, why is it not the same for the ajax urls?

Comment: 1) It will get from parameter of `validationEngine` function. 2) Because first it calls ajax url to validate the form, then used the form url to submit it.

Comment: `validateEngine` is a javascript function, which accept parameters, the second parameter is array with properties one of them is `ajaxFormValidationURL` that has a value of url generated by the struts tag prior the function is called.

Comment: sure that i got, ajaxFormValidationURL is now working with `<s:url>`. but the other ajax call in the last name input tag `<input id = "txtlname" name = "txtlname" type = "text" placeholder = "enter emp lname" class = "validate[required, ajax[ajaxStrutsCall]]" />` also uses ajax validation which is called from the `jquery.validationEngine-en.js` file, where i cant use tags.

Comment: the validation is made via one ajax call per validation, with all input fields.