# jquery validation engine ajax call to struts2 action not sending data

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp, struts2, jquery-validation-engine

using the jQuery validation engines built in Ajax functionality, i send a request from my last name field to my struts action class.
My HTML code is :

```
<script>
    $(document).ready (function ()
    {           
        $("#subform").validationEngine('attach', {
            autoHidePrompt : true , 
            autoHideDelay : 5000                
        }); 
    });
</script>

<body>

<div class = "container">                           
    <form id = "subform" action = "next" method = "post">           <br><br><br>
        First Name: <input id = "txtfname" name = "txtfname" type = "text" class = "validate[required]" 
            placeholder = "enter emp name" />
        Last name: <input id = "txtlname" name = "txtlname" type = "text" placeholder = "enter emp lname" 
                class = "validate[required, ajax[ajaxStrutsCall]]" />       
        Age: <input id = "txtage" name = "txtage" type = "text" placeholder = "enter age"  />           
        <input id ="cmdsubmit" type = "submit" name = "cmdsubmit" value = "click here" />
    </form>
</div>

</body>
```

the ajax[ajaxStrutsCall] refers to jquery.validationEngine-en.js for the url of the struts call.
jquery.validationEngine-en.js is :

```
"ajaxStrutsCall": {
                "url": "ajaxVal/LnameVal",
                "alertTextOk": "Your last name seems ok",
                "alertText": "Bad Last name",
                "alertTextLoad": "Validating, please wait"
            },
```

the url is mapped in my struts.xml file, which is :

```
<package name = "ajaxAction" namespace = "/ajaxVal" extends = "json-default">
    <action name = "LnameVal" class = "validation.struts.AjaxStrutsAction" method = "execute">
        <result name = "success" type = "json" />
    </action>
</package>
```

and finally my struts action class is :

```
public class AjaxStrutsAction extends ActionSupport implements ServletResponseAware, ServletRequestAware {

private HttpServletRequest request;
private HttpServletResponse response;

@Override
public void setServletRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
    this.request = request;
}
@Override
public void setServletResponse(HttpServletResponse response) {
    this.response = response;
}

@Override
public String execute() throws Exception {

    Gson gson = new Gson ();
    PrintWriter out = null;
    String data = request.getParameter("txtlname");
    System.out.println ("in struts class, got data from ajax query, lname is: " + data);

    try {
        Object [] ret = new Object [3];
        ret[0] = "txtlname";
        ret[1] = true;

        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        out = response.getWriter();
        out.write(gson.toJson(ret));

    }catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println ("error " + e.getStackTrace() );
    }finally {
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }

    return "success";
}
```

}

now, the response from the struts action class is proper, theres no issues there, but the data is not getting sent to the class, ie, `request.getParameter ("txtlname")` returns null, the name is not read by the class/sent by the request.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery validation engine in struts2 not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18635934/jquery-validation-engine-in-struts2-not-working)

Comment: yeah i asked the same question, but i had asked a couple of more problems with that question, and i didnt get an answer for this issue

Comment: as i already mentioned in my previous comment, i asked that question, but i did not get an answer to this issue, so, after i waited for two weeks, i trimmed down the question and asked it again.

Comment: also if you read both questions carefully, youll find that this question is not related to s:url tags at all, im hitting the struts action, but the data is not getting sent so s:url (which both answers in the other question use) is not the answer as i can call the struts action anyway, so downvoter, do your research next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, i figured this out, it seems that for individual field validations, the jquery validation engine sends the data with the name of the input field in `fieldId` and the actual value stored by it in `fieldValue`
so if `txtlname` is the name of the field, it is stored in fieldId and the value in fieldValue, so changing

`String data = request.getParameter("txtlname");`

to

```
String data = request.getParameter("fieldValue");
```

solved the problem